# How to Pass or Refer to original controller instance variable? SOLUTION

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, parameters

I am trying to understand how to refer back to a controller's instance variable in calling a method in the same controller with rendered the view.

I basically instantiate an instance variable in the controller with a list of modems.  In the view, I want to call an action to iterate over the instance variable array @modems and perform an action.  My problem is that I don't seem to be able to either reference the @modems instance variable in the action called nor can I pass it from the view.  If I try to pass the actual @modems back to the controller, I get a "connection reset" error page.  And to reference the original instance variable fails.  Haphazardly I tried to define/set @modem_cache in the application controller, then setting it equal to the @modems array in the getmodems method and then refer to it in the resetmodemcounters vs passing the instance variable back, did not work.  I'm sure there some fundamentals that I'm overlooking, but not seeing them.  I think I have included all the pertinent information.  Please indicate if I need to provide additional.  Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or how I might do it better I would greatly appreciate.

Thank you in Advance!

Controller app/controllers/cmts/cmts_controller.rb

```
def getmodems
  # Array of modems and stats (NOT ActiveRecord)
  @modems = Modems.all()
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :modems, :layout => "application" }
  end
end

# Called from modem.html.erb view
def resetmodemcounters
  if (session[:admin])
    params[:targets].each do |cm|
      # do action
    end
  end
end
```

View app/views/cmts/modems.html.rb

```
....
<%= link_to image_tag('recycle-red-button.png', :height => '30', :width => '35'), resetmodemcounters_path(:targets => @modems), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :get %>

<% @modems.each do |cm| %>
  <!-- Table of modem stats -->
<% end %>
....
```

Also tried this:

Controller app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ....
  @sweep_cache = nil
  ....
end
```

Controller app/controllers/cmts/cmts_controller.rb

```
def getmodems
  # Array of modems and stats (NOT ActiveRecord)
  @modems = Modems.all()
  @modems_cache = @modems
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :modems, :layout => "application" }
  end
end

def resetmodemcounters
  log(params)
  # {"_method"=>"get", "authenticity_token"=>"cZqSqAVKBpTiN5ZQSF1xUXMSiQmtDSQp8/6CRfis3Xs=", "target"=>"all", "controller"=>"cmts", "action"=>"resetmodemcounters"}
  log(@modems_cache)
  # nil

  if (session[:admin])
    if (params[:target] == 'all')
        @modems_cache.each do |cm|
          # do action
        end
    end
  end
end
```

View app/views/cmts/modems.html.rb

```
....
<%= link_to image_tag('recycle-red-button.png', :height => '30', :width => '35'), resetmodemcounters_path(:targets => 'all'), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :get %>

<% @modems.each do |cm| %>
  <!-- Table of modem stats -->
<% end %>
....
```

**HERE'S WHAT I CAME UP WITH and works** - Would there be a better way to handle this?

```
class ModemsCache
  DATA = []
  def update( modems )
    DATA.replace modems
  end
end

def getmodems
  # Array of modems and stats (NOT ActiveRecord)
  @modems = Modems.all()

  # Update Cache
  ModemsCache.new.update(@modems)

  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :modems, :layout => "application" }
  end
end

def resetmodemcounters
  if (session[:admin])

    # Get Cached Data
    modems = ModemsCache::DATA

    modems.each do |cm|
      # do action
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you're question.  Once a view renders, the controller action is completed.  You can pass parameters back from the view upon calling *another* controller action, but performing additional functionality in the same controller action *after* a view is rendered is not possible.  Or do I not understand your question?

Comment: @CDub - Thank you, I am indeed calling a separate controller action.  The original controller action/method that renders the modems view is the "getmodems" action.  From the view I am calling the "resetmodemcounters" action in the same controller.